# How to detect frametype I, P, B in mpegts stream in gstreamer tsdemux

Tags: c++, video-streaming, gstreamer, frame

I am learner of gstreamer. Recently came across a problem while working on a project I am not getting a way how to detect frametype in gstreamer mpegts stream.
I have to make some changes in tsdemux itself so that it can just detect and print the types in console or generate some txt file with Timestamp data and frametype.

I tried creating one separate element but looks like I am having logical issue in that or maybe I am not understanding things properly.

I have tried to understand the code but facing challenge in understanding the flow and not getting where the frames are being handled inside tsdemux. Please help